# How to bundle node module CSS into a vscode extension

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, vscode-extensions

My Visual Studio Code extension uses the node module `highlight.js` which comes with a folder full of CSS files. These provide colour schemes for syntax colouring. It has become necessary to bundle some of the CSS files.

## It's about bundling an asset

The objective is to **bundle a CSS file and at run-time access the file content as a string**. If that can be achieved *without* an import statement that would be perfect. Normally, how exactly one accesses the content of the bundled file would be a separate question, but I have a feeling that content retrieval and how one should go about bundling the asset are closely entwined.

I freely admit to having a weak understanding of WebPack.

## The story so far

The bundler is specified in `package.json` as `"webpack": "^5.4.0"` but I don't know how to ascertain what is actually present. It is conceivable that there is something wrong with my setup: when I try to run `webpack --version` on a command prompt in the project folder, it responds

```
CLI for webpack must be installed.
  webpack-cli (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli)

We will use "npm" to install the CLI via "npm install -D webpack-cli".
Do you want to install 'webpack-cli' (yes/no):
```

The first time this happened I responded yes. After a flurry of installation and another try the same thing happened. However, `vsce package` has no trouble using webpack for a production build and pressing `F5` to debug successfully puts together a development build in a `dist` folder with an unminified file I can examine (which is how I know the file mentioned below is being bundled).

Moving on from there I've modified `webpack.config.js` like so

```js
//@ts-check

'use strict';

const path = require('path');

/**@type {import('webpack').Configuration}*/
const config = {
  target: 'node', // vscode extensions run in a Node.js-context -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

  entry: './src/extension.ts', // the entry point of this extension, -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
  output: {
    // the bundle is stored in the 'dist' folder (check package.json), -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'extension.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '../[resource-path]'
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  externals: {
    vscode: 'commonjs vscode' // the vscode-module is created on-the-fly and must be excluded. Add other modules that cannot be webpack'ed, -> https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/
  },
  resolve: {
    // support reading TypeScript and JavaScript files, -> https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.css']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

As you can see there are rules and loaders for CSS.

When I add this import

```
import "../node_modules/highlight.js/styles/atelier-dune-light.css";
```

webpack happily builds the bundle and when I inspect it I can find the bundled CSS.

However, when I try to load the extension in the extension debug host, it fails to load, with this message.

> Activating extension 'pdconsec.vscode-print' failed: document is not defined.

Enabling break on caught exceptions reveals this rather surprising exception.

```
Exception has occurred: Error: Cannot find module 'supports-color'
Require stack:
- c:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\get-uri\node_modules\debug\src\node.js
- c:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\get-uri\node_modules\debug\src\index.js
- c:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\get-uri\dist\index.js
- c:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\vscode-proxy-agent\out\agent.js
- c:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules.asar\vscode-proxy-agent\out\index.js
- c:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
- c:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js
```

OK, so activation failed because the loader barfed. But WTF does importing CSS have to do with `support-color`?

Remove the import and it runs just fine. I really don't know how to respond to this; it's not clear to me why a demand for a stylesheet should cause that error. At this point I look to others for guidance and advice.

Comment: Have you looked at the suggestions on [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-mock-debug/issues/31)?

Comment: You had my hopes up but I actually started from the setup they suggest. The loader error is preventing my extension from starting. That said, thank you - I'm going to add to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `style-loader` from `webpack.config.js` to fix the error.

Pull the CSS as a string like this. Note the abbreviated path.

```js
const cssPath: string = "highlight.js/styles/atelier-dune-light.css";
const theCss: string = require(cssPath).default.toString();
```

You do not need the `import` statement, the use of `require` will cause Webpack to bundle the files, but you still have to remove style-loader to avoid the loader error.